# Electron interference

Tags: electrons, electronic-configuration

Assuming that electrons behave as both waves and particles, and that waves(like in double slit experiment) can interfere with themselves:

1. Do electrons actually move in any direction, or do they just 'teleport'(similar to how when making a Quantum Leap, they instantaneously appear at a different shell, rather than actually move continuously).
2. Do electrons 'subtract' with other electrons for the probability function of an electron being present in that location. i.e. if there is a covalent bond, will the electrons interfere with the other probably function aside from repelling it?.
3. Do electrons only have positive probabilities. Is it more like how gravity never repels, only attracts, or more similar to how waves of light have peaks and troughs. Do electrons ever cancel out with others? If so, how?

Comment: Just a short comment to the third question: probability is non-negative by definition. See [probability axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms).

Comment: And to add to @Wildcat's comments, $\psi^*\psi$ will, by construction, always be positive real. Of course there can be interference - there are places where the probability is zero.

Comment: Ok,thanks, but @GeoffHutchison how can they interfere to be zero probability if it is only positive? Wouldn't that cause the probability to add together, not cancel to zero?

Comment: @Brayton The wave functions can be negative (or imaginary or complex). The probability is the square of the wavefunction, or more accurately $\psi^*\psi$ so of course the probability cannot be negative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Traditional understanding of trajectory is of no use for electrons. Granted, on macroscale you may detect something close to movement and trajectory, (electron beams and electron cannons take their names from this) but it still far from what we have in classical mechanics. Ideally you should abandon any attempts to relate quantum and classical mechanics and view quantum mechanics as an abstract mathematical construct.
2. Incorrect question. If you have a system of two or more particles, you should consider the wavefunction of combined system, not separate wavefunctions for separate particles. Still, for electrons being fermions, there is a strict rule that wavefunction must be zero for positions in phase-space where two electrons of same spin are at same location and since electrons are of same charge, probability of having two electrons of different sping close to each other is usually lower than to have them at some distance.
3. Yes, only positive probabilities. Though, this does no apply to wavefunction itself, it may be negative at some point (actually, its value can be a complex number).